# set out of stock configurable products visibility to search

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, search, out-of-stock, visibility

A configurable product is `out of stock` when all its simple products are `out of stock`.

I would like to set the `visibility` to `search` for all configurable products which are `out of stock` in bulk.

Can anyone help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter products by type - Configurable, then manually go through each and see if stock status of associated simple products are out of stock, then you need to:

1. Check the boxes next to configurable products you want to update
2. Select 'Actions' -> Update attributes -> Submit (on the right)
3. There  will be field for visibility you can select necessary from drop-down for selected products.

Here is also the video on ways to set [visibility](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADQBNA75sZo) in Magento.

Comment: Thank you, I said how to do it in bulk, what if there are thousands of products.